# Understanding defer sorting example in ng-table demo

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the example shown here
http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/3

Here are some snippets of it:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This the data initialization at the js script:

```
var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
```

There are two things I can not understand:
1. Why is there a $ sign in the ng-repeat clause?   `<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">`
If i take the $ of, the example doesn't work.

2. I don't understand the $defer part in the example. I tried reading the docs and view examples about what defer does and just didn't get it.
   How calling:

   ```
   $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
   ```

   }

effects the scope data parameter and is it related to the fact it has a dollar sign at the html (as i mentioned at the previous question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Name of array holding elements for table have nothing to do with
   with actual object exposed to $scope. You can change occurrence of
   'data' in DemoCtrl and you will see it.
   **$data** is object exposed to the [ng-table directive scope](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/ng-table.js#L411) after resolving promise in **getData** method.
2. I still have problems with $defers. Your question motivated me to fill knowledge gap:

   [Promises in AngularJS and where to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604196/promises-in-angularjs-and-where-to-use-them)

   [AngularJS Promises - The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770325/AngularJS-Promises-The-Definitive-Guide)