# How can I wrap the $http service and have the data it fetches used in a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

What I want to do is have the $http call wrapped so I can use it as a function everywhere in my app without using it directly. Also, according to what I receive from the server I want to display a message, or other general things and separate the logic. My problem is I can't reach the data sent by the server. What am I doing wrong?

This is my service I wrapped the $http in:

```
Application.service('test', ['$http', function ($http)
{
    this.test = function()
    {
        console.log('testttt');
    }

    this.fetchData = function(url, successCallback, errorCallback, parameters)
    {
        if (parameters)
        {
            $http.get(url, {params: parameters})
                .success(function (data) {
                    successCallback();
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    errorCallback();
                })
                .finally(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
        }
        else
        {
            $http.get(url)
                .success(successCallback)
                .error(errorCallback)
                .finally(function(data) {
                    console.log('finally');
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.message)
                        console.log(message);
                });
        }

    }
}])
```

And the controller where I call it:

```
Application.controller('AccessLoggingController', ['$scope', '$http', 'initData', 'test', function($scope, $http, initData,test)
{
    test.fetchData('/jewelry-room/move-user.action', function(){}, function(){}, {user:2000, task:7});
... etc more code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need to pass success and error callbacks, since `$http.get` returns a promise. From [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation:

> The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q
>   service. While for simple usage patterns this doesn't matter much, for
>   advanced usage it is important to familiarize yourself with these APIs
>   and the guarantees they provide.

In order to understand deferred and promises [please see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604196/promises-in-angularjs-and-where-to-use-them).

`fetchData` function may look like:

```
this.fetchData = function(url, parameters) {
    return $http.get(url, {params: parameters}).then(
        function(response) {
            // do something 
            return response; // resolves a promise 
        }, 
        function(response) {
            // do something
            return $q.reject("Unable to fetch!"); // rejects a promise  
        });
}
```

Then you can use a service in controllers:

```
test.fetchData('/jewelry-room/move-user.action', {user:2000, task:7}).then(
    function(result) {
        // success callback
        $scope.action = result;    
    }, 
    function(result) {
        // error callback
        $window.alert(result); // alerts "Unable to fetch!"
    });
```

Alternatively, if you still want to pass callbacks for some reason:

```
this.fetchData = function(url, successCallback, errorCallback, parameters) {
    return $http.get(url, {params: parameters}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Comment: i see what you mean, but i need to treat the response in my fetchData function first, and then pass the data further, because i need to send some kind of feedback to the user when the server messes up

Comment: Since `then` returns a promise as well, you can chain them. [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) documentation has some explanation of the promise chaining. 
Please see my edited answer.

Comment: the functions in then are its respective success and error callbacks?

Comment: Exactly. It is `then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)`.

Comment: things finally start to make sense. thank you for your help mr constantine

Answer (score 0):

I think your callbacks should take a data param i.e

`test.fetchData('/jewelry-room/move-user.action', function(data){}, function(data){}, {user:2000, task:7});`

And in fetchData method you should pass the data param i.e

`successCallback(data);`