# Async function pass data to async function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I have the following code:

```
//calling AsyncFunction
var coords = LocationSerivice.getLocation();
var localStores;

 setTimeout(function(){

            //works
            console.log(coords);

            //calling async function again
            localStores = LocalStoresService.getLocalStores(coords[0],coords[1]);



        }, 100);

        setTimeout(function(){

                    //doesn't work
                    console.log(localStores);



               }, 100);
```

What am I trying to do is to first call a Async function that returns my location. Then in order to get the data from that function I am setting timeout. With the data received I am calling second Async function. And again I am setting timeout in order to get the data from my second Async function, so here it fails. If I try to display the data with `console.log()` in the timeout block it says `undefined` while `console.log()`in the first timeout block works.

I have tried also increasing the timeout time but it just doesn't work. 
Any suggestions how to get over that ?

Comment: You need to correctly pass callbacks.  See http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: One of your tags is angularjs so I'd suggest you look into `promise`s http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604196/promises-in-angularjs-and-where-to-use-them

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your `LocalStoresService.getLocalStores` method to accept a callback.

```
function getLocalStores (arg1, arg2, cb) {
    // do stuff.
    var localStores = 'w/e';
    if (typeof cb === 'function') return cb(localStores);
}
```

So your invoking method would look like this:

```
var coords = LocationService.getLocation();

LocalStoresService.getLocalStores(coords[0], coords[1], function (localStores) {
    console.log(localStores); // 'w/e'
});
```

It really depends on the type of technology you're using, as the "correct" implementation of async methods can vary from type to type (AngularJS, NodeJS, vanilla JS etc..)

Comment: One of the tags on the question is angularjs, so I think a promise is the way to go

Comment: I completely agree, Angular is at Ionic's core, so there's no argue there. I gave an example for vanilla JS as it seems to me he's at beginner's level.

Comment: Wonderful ! Promises sloved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your project might be using angularjs i am giving example based on that ,

```
.factory('LocationSerivice', function ($http) {

return{

     getLocation : function () {
       return  $http.get('location_api');
     };

     getLocalStores : function(coords){
       return $http.get('your_local_store_api');
     };

  }
 });
```

Now call your API's

```
LocationService.getLocation().success(function(coords){
       LocationService.getLocalStores(coords).success(function(localStores){
           console.log(localStores);
       });
});
```