# How to wait for 3 Facebook Async functions to complete before pushing to array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous

I have an array of facebook posts that I have each processed into a structured format, such as:

```
var refined_posts = [];
var refined_post = {
   info1: info1,
   info2: info2,
   username: username,
   profilelink: profilelink
}
```

info1 and info2 is returned from my first Async Facebook Graphs API call, which grabs a facebook post:

```
   // Get the facebook post
   FB.api(
        "/142679255268",
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            info1: response.info1,
            info2: response.info2,
            postid: response.id
          }
        }
    );
```

And after than I have 2 other Async calls for extracting the user name of a facebook post, and the profile link URL:

```
        // Get the name of the poster
        FB.api(
            '/'+postid+'?fields=from',
            function (response) {
              if (response && !response.error) {
                username = response.from.name;
              }
            }
        );

        // Get the profile link of the user
        FB.api(
            '/'+username+'?fields=link',
            function (response) {
              if (response && !response.error) {
                profilelink= response.link;
              }
            }
        );
```

And then finally, I push the refined_post to the array.

```
refined_posts.push(refined_post);
```

However, currently the refined_post will get pushed to the array before the last 2 async calls complete. How can I make the push wait for all Facebook async calls to finish before pushing?

I am using AngularJS but I would also like to be able to reuse my frontend code in my NodeJS backend. For now my priority is getting this to work on the frontend. Any ideas?

Comment: Either promises or callback functions will solve this.  Obviously since you are using Angular you will use $q.defer();

Comment: look into async https://github.com/caolan/async if you would like to use callbacks

Comment: async github.com/caolan/async looks good, I knew itd have to be callbacks or promises. I was hoping someone knew off the top of their head specifically which functions I should use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604196/angularjs-where-to-use-promises this has some facebook examples in it I think

Comment: No need for external promise library when angular already has `$q` built in

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments by @user2950720 async would solve this easily, here is an example

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) on this

***************UPDATE***************

It would look something like this for you

```
var refined_posts = [];
var refined_post = {};

async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        // Get the facebook post
        FB.api(
            "/142679255268",
            function (response) {
                var err = null;
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    refined_post = {
                        info1: response.info1,
                        info2: response.info2,
                        postid: response.id
                    };
                } else {
                    err = response.error;
                }

                callback(err);
            }
        );
    },
    function(callback) {
        // Get the name of the poster
        FB.api(
            '/'+postid+'?fields=from',
            function (response) {
                var err = null;
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    refined_post.username = response.from.name;
                } else {
                    err = response.error;
                }

              callback(err);
            }
        );
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // Get the profile link of the user
        FB.api(
            '/'+username+'?fields=link',
            function (response) {
                var err = null;
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    refined_post.profilelink= response.link;
                } else {
                    err = response.error;
                }

                callback(err);
            }
        );
    }
], function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        refined_posts.push(refined_post)
    } else {
        // do something with your error
    }
});
```

Comment: Would I be able to change the value of global variables outside the function?

Comment: Yes you can access a global variable in the waterfall function